# save multiple record in single column by coma sepration, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-select

In my app, I use multiple countries select(check box) to store multiple countries name in a single column. for this I'm using `country-select` gem and in view page:

```
 .field
    = f.label :current_country
    = f.country_select :current_country, options_for_select( ["--Select--"] , f.object.current_country), {}, {:multiple => true }
```

By using this, I'm able to select multiple counties, but it is not properly save in db (eg. ---- Afghanistan- Aland Islands- Algeria). How can I save multiple countries as comma seprated way (like Afghanistan, Aland Islands, Algeria )

Comment: Comma sep's in db columns is a really bad idea and may bite you on the bum in the future - consider changing your schema to have a 1:m relationship between Countries and Counties. Just my two penneth worth.

Comment: hey @bUKaneer , Thanks for your very quick reply. In my app I'm using multi select in 4-5 fields so I think it lengthy to create relation for each 4-5 fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think that database relation will be better but if you really want to you can use database serialize

Take a look on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

It means that you can serialize for example array, and then when read attribute it will deserialize and you will see ruby object - array

You can take a look also here http://weblog.bitlasoft.com/2010/05/ruby-on-rails-serializing-and-deserializing-ruby-objects/